# form submit with multiple checkbox - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am codeigniter php developer.so , i need to send the database multiple checkbox values.first of all i created table with prefer, holiday, facility and accomadation fields.

controller

```
if($_POST)
{
    $prefer= $this->input->post('prefer');
    $data['prefer'] = array(
            'prefer' => implode(",", $prefer),
        ); 

    $holiday= $this->input->post('holiday');
    $data = array(
            'holiday' => implode(",", $holiday),      
        );
    $facility= $this->input->post('facility');
    $data = array(
            'facility' => implode(",", $facility),      
        );
    $accommodation= $this->input->post('accommodation');
    $data = array(
            'accommodation' => implode(",", $accommodation),      
        );

    $this->customize->save_customize_tour_detail($data);
}
```

view

Wild & adventurous

```
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="prefer[]" value="romantic"  />Romantic & sensuous
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="prefer[]" value="healthy"  />Healthy & rejuvenating
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="prefer[]" value="fun"  />Fun & exciting
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="prefer[]" value="peaceful"  />Thought provoking & peaceful
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="prefer[]" value="shopping"  />Shopping
                        </label>
                    </div></div>

                    <div style="float:left">
                    <label for=""><font color="#00CC66">What whould you like to see in a holiday?</font></label>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="holiday[]" value="beach"  />Beaches
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="holiday[]" value="wild"  />Wild life
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="holiday[]" value="fauna"  />Fauna & flora
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="holiday[]" value="archeological"  />Archeological sites
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="holiday[]" value="mountains"  />Mountains & waterfalls
                        </label>
                    </div></div></div>
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                    <div>
                  <div style="float:left; margin-right:30px;">

                    <label for=""><font color="#00CC66">What is the most important facility you need?</font></label>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="facility[]" value="comfortable"  />Comfortable accommodation
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="facility[]" value="transportation"  />Transportation
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="facility[]" value="guide"  />Guide assistance
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="facility[]" value="excellent"  />Excellent food
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="facility[]" value="communication"  />Communication
                        </label>
                    </div></div>

                  <div style="float:left">
                    <label for=""><font color="#00CC66">What kind of accommodation pleases you?</font></label>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="accommodation[]" value="standard_duest_house"  />Standard Guest Houses
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="accommodation[]" value="three_star"  />3 Star Hotels
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="accommodation[]" value="five_star"  />5 Star Hotels
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="accommodation[]" value="two_star"  />2 Star Hotels
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="accommodation[]" value="four_star"  />4 Star Hotels
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

model

```
function save_customize_tour_detail($data) {
    $this->db->insert('ba_customize_tours',$data);
}
```

problem is when i click the send button only accomadation value goes to table.others(prefer,holoday,facility) values not going to table.

Comment: Try this one
Use batch insert see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015852/codeigniters-insert-batch-with-thousands-of-inserts-has-missing-records

Comment: use insert_batch instead insert only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $prefer= $this->input->post('prefer');
    $data['prefer'] =implode(",", $prefer);           

    $holiday= $this->input->post('holiday');
    $data['holiday'] = implode(",", $holiday);  

    $facility= $this->input->post('facility');
    $data['facility'] = implode(",", $facility);

    $accommodation= $this->input->post('accommodation');
    $data['accommodation'] = implode(",", $accommodation);


    $this->customize->save_customize_tour_detail($data);
}
```

Comment: it is work perfect..thank you so much your promp support